# When to use an iterator in Tensorflow Estimator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

In the Tensorflow guides there are two separate places where the guide describes the input function for the Iris Data example. One input function returns just the dataset itself, while the other returns the dataset with an iterator.

From the premade Estimator guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/premade_estimators

```
def train_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
"""An input function for training"""
# Convert the inputs to a Dataset.
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))

# Shuffle, repeat, and batch the examples.
return dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(batch_size)
```

From the custom estimator guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/custom_estimators

```
def train_input_fn(features, labels, batch_size):
"""An input function for training"""
# Convert the inputs to a Dataset.
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))

# Shuffle, repeat, and batch the examples.
dataset = dataset.shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(batch_size)

# Return the read end of the pipeline.
return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

I'm confused which one is correct, and if they both are used for different cases, when is it correct to return the dataset using an iterator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your input function returns a `tf.data.Dataset`, an iterator is created under the hood and its `get_next()` function is used to supply inputs to the model. This is somewhat hidden in the source code, see `parse_input_fn_result` [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.11/tensorflow/python/estimator/util.py).

I believe this was only implemented in a more recent update, so older tutorials still explicitly return `get_next()` in their input function since it was the only option back then.  There should be no difference between using either, but you can save a tiny bit of code by returning the dataset instead of the iterator.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for this. This was really confusing me as well until I read your response. I don't think this issue is explicitly mentioned in the documentation. The only oblique reference found was a code snippet in the performance guide. https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets . You are right, seems like now you can just return the dataset at the end of the `input_fn` and the estimator will know what to do.

Comment: The input function should return a `tf.data.Dataset` if used with a DistributionStrategy. `ValueError: dataset_fn() must return a tf.data.Dataset when using a DistributionStrategy.`

Comment: Another caveat is that some operations on the dataset needs to be done inside the input function as discussed here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/8042
and
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4026